# error in accessing variables from variable file on grid file

Tags: css, sass

I have already:

1. imported both abstracts/variables and layout/grid on `main.scss` [importing files of variables and working file of the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dWfS.jpg)
2. assigned variable on `_variables.scss` [variables assigned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq7RC.jpg)

I am using the variables on grid file under the folder, layout ,  [calling variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8jM2.jpg) the variables are assigned on variables file under folder abstracts.

Why is it showing error?

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NArOT.jpg) saying undefined variable when i try to save the file and refresh the page, it says the same for all variables. I can't use any variables from the partial variables file on partial grid.
Can someone help me with it please?

[Overall format, the tree structure of folders and files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Tuu.jpg)

Comment: Welcome. You should copy and paste the relevant code into your question, as opposed to adding pictures of code.

Comment: Have a read of: 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question